# Using $.when to wait for ajax to complete

Tags: jquery, .when

I need to wait for a certain ajax request to complete before going on. Since this request is triggered from different anchors, I wrapped it in a function.
What happens after the function with the first ajax has finished, is a second ajax request.

At first, I tried to wait for the first to finish using `$.ajaxComplete()` which ran into an endless loop because of the second ajax request performed thereafter.

I found some samples about using `$.when` but none of them showed whether it's possible to use a method instead deferreds.

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
$.when( functionFirstAjaxCall(data) ).then( function() {
    // after first ajax request has finished, do the following:
    $.ajax({
        //...
    });
});
```

Does `functionFirstAjaxCall()` need to have a certain return value or how can I get this one working? By the way, the solution doesn't need to use `$.when`.

**Update**: I got it working by creating a custom event as Vandesh has advised.

```
function first() {
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function (d) {
            $.event.trigger({
                type: "finished",
                data: d
            });
         }
    });
}

$(document).on('finished', second());
```

Anyway, would there be a simple solution by using `$.when`?

Comment: create a function with the second ajax and run it in `success:function(){...}` or `done:` from the first ajax?

Comment: `success` is deprecated as of JQuery 1.8 - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we can! Dose something like this work for you?

```
function first() {
    var a = $.ajax({
        // ...
    });
    return a.promise();
}

first().done(function(){
    //Im done
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like -

```
$.ajax({// First AJAX call
    url: ""
}).done(function() {
    $.ajax({//Second AJAX call on completion of first
        url: ""
    }).done(function() {

    });
});
```

Find more on usage of [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: No, the first ajax is triggered on more occasions. The two don't go hand in hand. That's why I packed it into a function. I can't do `functionFirstAjaxCall().done(function(){ ... });` can I?

Comment: You can try that using jQuery events - .bind() and .trigger()
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Write your custom event which will trigger when your function is completed and bind the second AJAX call to that event